# ColdFusion - OAuthException - This authorization code has expired. [code=100]

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, railo, cfml

I am having a go at trying to get the Facebook API SDK for ColdFusion working.

https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk

I have followed all the steps and it seems to work well (using only server-side login).

However, if I leave the page for say, an hour, when I return and refresh the page (which was showing my profile name and friends list) it shows up with an error that I am unable to get rid of, unless I clear the cookies.

Is there something I am missing with this FB login? Am I meant to be checking against something manually in order to persist the session?

Looking at my cookies, I have the following stored:

1. fbm_155030275875
2. fbsr_155030275875
3. CFID
4. CFTOKEN

It's all new to me, so I'm a bit lost. I can't see anything in the docs for the SDK about this and *Googling* the error brings nothing.

I have attached a screenshot of the error.

[image]

I'd appreciate any help you can offer!

Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar enough with that particular project, but in general, your code should be requesting the various Graph API calls, and requesting the token as necessary. If the token has expired, you request a new one. I'd expect the facebook-cf-sdk product to do this, but again, I'm unfamiliar with it.

Good news is, the Facebook Graph API is just a series of HTTP calls. See my talk at NC DevCon for an example of logging in and making some graph calls: (a bit long; go to about the 1:42:00 mark)

http://textiles.online.ncsu.edu/online/Play/61d0900d63fd4c1cb862622d1c8e13521d?catalog=35211b84-031b-4a18-8875-506f09b9b3a7

GitHub repo:
https://github.com/bdcravens/ncdevcon2012-handson-auth (note the branches - check out the step4 branch)

These don't answer your question 100%, but they may be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out how to solve this issue using a solution someone provided on Github.  I just wanted to post this here in case someone else encountered the issue and wasn't sure how to solve it.  In my case however, after I applied the solution from that post was I need to do a page refresh.  Link below.

https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk/issues/31